# How do I use `filterValues` on Nested Hashmap Iteration in Kotlin?

Tags: java, functional-programming, hashmap, kotlin

I am trying to iterate through a nested Hashmap in a more functional style using Kotlin.  In particular, I have two HashMap instances (both of type `Map<String, Integer>`) and I want to match up their values based on some criteria.  Here is the Java method of what I want to achieve:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> pairs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> oldImages : startingImageMap.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> newImages : finalImageMap.entrySet()) {
        Integer oldImageVal = oldImages.getValue();
        Integer newImageVal = newImages.getValue();

        boolean containsNewType = pairs.containsKey(newImageVal) &&
                pairs.get(newImageVal).intValue() == oldImageVal.intValue();

        boolean urlsMatch = newImages.getKey().equals(oldImages.getKey());

        if (!containsNewType && urlsMatch) {
            pairs.put(oldImageVal, newImageVal);
        }
    }
}

return pairs;
```

Here is my attempt at functional equivalent in Kotlin:

```
private val swapPairs: Map<Int, Int>
    get() {
        val pairs = LinkedHashMap<Int, Int>()

        startingImageMap.forEach {
            val finalImageMap = finalImageMap.filterValues {
                val containsNewType = pairs.containsKey(it) && pairs[it] == startingImageMap[it]
                val urlMatch = it == startingImageMap[it]

                return !containsNewType && urlsMatch
            }.values.first()     
        }
        return pairs
    }
```

I am stuck on how to do this properly using `filterValues`.
What does the correct solution look like in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this is a stateful filter, meaning that the decision to put an element in the final result depends on previous elements processed.  Functional filters should be stateless, so the decision to add an element is the same regardless of the order the elements are processed.

However, I think the whole logic is a bit verbose.

You could rewrite the Java version like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> pairs = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> oldImages : startingImageMap.entrySet()) {
  Integer oldImageVal = oldImages.getValue();
  Integer newImageVal = finalImageMap.get(oldImages.getKey());

  if (newImageVal != null) {
    boolean containsNewType = pairs.containsKey(newImageVal) &&
        pairs.get(newImageVal).intValue() == oldImageVal.intValue();

    if (!containsNewType) {
      pairs.put(oldImageVal, newImageVal);
    }
  }
}

return pairs;
```

Which is much shorter and does the same thing.

It is however still stateful due the external map `pairs` being checked with `containsKey`.

I'm wondering though what the expected output of the function will be in this case:

```
   old       new
  A: 1       A: 5
  B: 2       B: 2
  C: 3       C: 3
  D: 4       E: 8
  H: 9       F: 9
             G: 3
```

Could you add the expected result?  I have the impression the function is flawed.